# Can I rely on a pytest test parametrization to be passed on to a fixture?

Tags: pytest, fixtures, parametrized-testing

Here's a minimal example of a behaviour that I "discovered":

```py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def introduce_yourself(my_name):
    return f"Hello, my name is {my_name}"


@pytest.mark.parametrize("my_name", ["Alice", "Bob"])
def test_introduction(introduce_yourself):
    print(introduce_yourself)
```

When running `pytest`, it yields the results:

```bash
platform linux -- Python 3.10.11, pytest-7.3.1, pluggy-1.0.0
Using --randomly-seed=37854407
rootdir: /home/REDACTED
configfile: pyproject.toml
plugins: mock-3.10.0, cov-4.0.0, randomly-3.12.0
collected 2 items

REDACTED/tryout.py::test_introduction[Alice] Hello, my name is Alice
PASSED
REDACTED/tryout.py::test_introduction[Bob] Hello, my name is Bob
PASSED
```

So it seems the parametrization of `test_introduction` is passed on to the fixture `introduce_yourself`.

I found this behaviour described [in a medium.com article](https://medium.com/@yavinarba/pytest-fixtures-super-dry-tests-with-calleable-nested-fixtures-f8bcede38eb7) but I cannot find anything in the [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/).
**Is this behaviour intentional and can be relied upon?**

Thanks and cheers!